# JAX-RS response with HTTP status 500 instead of HTTP status 400

Tags: java, json, jackson, jax-rs, cxf

Sometimes JAR-RS clients are sending wrong syntactical request body. The server should response with [HTTP status 400 (Bad Request)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.1), but it responses with [HTTP status 500 (Internal Server Error)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.6.1).

**Code:**

JAX-B model class:

```
@XmlRootElement(namespace = "http://www.test.com/test")
@XmlAccessorType(value = XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class TestModel {

    @XmlElement
    private String id;
}
```

JAX-RS resource class:

```
@Path("test")
public class TestResource {

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public void create(TestModel testModel) {
        // some code
    }
}
```

CXF configuration:

```
<jaxrs:server address="/rest" id="test" staticSubresourceResolution="true">
    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <ref bean="testResource" /> 
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
    <jaxrs:providers>
        <bean class="com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJaxbJsonProvider" />
    </jaxrs:providers>
</jaxrs:server>
```

**Example:**

Request body:

```
{"id2": "test"}
```

The `id2` is wrong, so client should get a [HTTP status 400](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.1), but it gets [HTTP status 500](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.6.1).

Server log:

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "id2" (class test.TestModel), not marked as ignorable (one known property: "id"])
    at [Source: org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination$1@6f30793d; line: 1, column: 10] (through reference chain: test.TestModel["id2"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException.from(UnrecognizedPropertyException.java:51)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportUnknownProperty(DeserializationContext.java:839)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer.handleUnknownProperty(StdDeserializer.java:1045)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.handleUnknownProperty(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1352)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.handleUnknownVanilla(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1330)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:264)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:125)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader._bind(ObjectReader.java:1470)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader.readValue(ObjectReader.java:912)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.base.ProviderBase.readFrom(ProviderBase.java:811)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.readFromMessageBodyReader(JAXRSUtils.java:1343)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.readFromMessageBody(JAXRSUtils.java:1294)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.processParameter(JAXRSUtils.java:826)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.processParameters(JAXRSUtils.java:789)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSInInterceptor.processRequest(JAXRSInInterceptor.java:212)
    ... 68 more
```

Is there a way to configure Jackson and/or CXF to return HTTP status 400 for wrong syntactical request body without [schema validation](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-data-bindings.html#JAX-RSDataBindings-Schemavalidation) or [bean validation](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-data-bindings.html#JAX-RSDataBindings-BeanValidation)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that exceptions that aren't mapped to response (by way of [`ExceptionMapper`](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/representations.html#d0e6665)s), translate to a general server error response, as the runtime has no idea what to do with the exception.

The `jackson-jaxrs-provider` module has `ExceptionMapper`s to handle the Jackson base exception class `JsonMappingException` and `JsonParseException`. The mappers are [`JsonMappingExceptionMapper`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-jaxrs-providers/blob/master/base/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/jaxrs/base/JsonMappingExceptionMapper.java) and [`JsonParseExceptionMapper`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-jaxrs-providers/blob/master/base/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/jaxrs/base/JsonParseExceptionMapper.java), respectively. These mappers will map the exception to a 400 response along with the exception message as the response body. If you do not like this response body, you can just write your own mapper.