# JAX-RS / Jersey : Change response body from Jackson JSON errors

Tags: json, jersey, jackson, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I have a rest end point using jersey, and I "drop" the payload in a DTO with a field which is ENUM type.

```java
public enum AdminStatus {
   ACTIVE, NONACTIVE;
}

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class AdminUpdateDTO {

  @XmlElement(nillable = false, required = true)
  private AdminStatus status;

  public AdminStatus getStatus() {
      return status;
  }

  public void setStatus(AdminStatus status) {
     this.status = status;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
     return "[status=" + this.getStatus() + "]";
  }
}
```

When I give this field a value that not match with the existing ENUM values and make a request I get this:

> Can not construct instance of com.utility.AdminStatus from String value 'ACTIVEE': 
>     value not one of declared Enum instance names: [NONACTIVE, ACTIVE]
>        at [Source:          org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$UnCloseableInputStream@2848cd9d; line: 1, column: 328] (through reference chain: com.dto.AdminUpdateDTO["status"])

Does Jersey has ability to handle this somehow, i mean, i don't want to get this as a response but some custom error response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the default behavior of the Jackson provider exception mappers: to return the exception message as the response. If you want a different response, [create your own mappers](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/representations.html#d0e6665) for `JsonMappingException` and `JsonParseException`, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36866271/2587435).

#### UPDATE

here are a couple examples

```
@Provider
public class JsonMappingExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<JsonMappingException> {
    @Override
    public Response toResponse(JsonMappingException exception) {
        return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST)
                .entity("Boo..").type("text/plain").build();
    }
}

@Provider
public class JsonParseExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<JsonParseException> {
    @Override
    public Response toResponse(JsonParseException exception) {
        return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST)
                .entity("Boo...").type("text/plain").build();
    }
}
```

Here the response will simply be `Boo...`. You need to make sure these mappers are registered. If you are using scanning, the class should be picked up from the `@Provider` annotation. Otherwise you will need to manually register, whichever way you register your resources and providers.

Comment: Ok, but it throws this error before even get into the rest end point method body.

Comment: As it should. The error happens during deserialization, which happens before the resource method is called. The exception is caught by the `ExceptionMapper` that Jackson implemented, which just returns the exception message. You need to implement your own `ExceptionMapper` for a different response.

Comment: Are you having some problems implementing your own `ExceptionMapper`?

Comment: Yes, can u point me to some example how to implement this exception?

Comment: Both links I provided. The last link shows you the exact implementation Jackson uses. The first documentation link, you need to scroll down maybe the size of your screen